# How do you call an element that is non-zero non-unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm doing a mathematical formalization of Unique-Factorization Domains. But I can't find proper definitions.

I want to know how you call a **non-zero non-unit element** of a ring. Also I would like to have a precise definition of **reducible element**, and **composite element**, if these exists, preverably with references included.

Regards,
Jens

Comment: Usually one just says "nonzero non-unit", just like that. An element of a commutative ring is called irreducible is it's a nonzero non-unit and is not expressible as a product of two non-units. The term "composite" is not used.

Comment: I would go exactly with that: a non-zero non-unit. For example, what is $\;2\in\Bbb Z\;$? A non-zero non-unit element in the ring of integers...Reducible and composite elements (if this is what you meant with "composition")  are, as far as I know, the same in UFD's, and they're simply elements which aren't neither units nor primes.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but: what is a **composition element**? Would 4, 6, 8, 9 be considered "composition elements" in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Robert Soupe, I made a spelling mistake, it should be composite.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Jens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly that: "nonzero non-unit" (we can quibble about spacing and hyphens, though).

In some contexts, you might even be able to say just "nonzero" or "non-unit" because the other is clear by context. e.g., you ask the reader to "divide $a$ by non-unit $b$" (you probably don't want to divide by $0$, unless the domain you're working in has zero-divisors, so you dispense with "nonzero").

A **reducible element** is an element that is the product of two or more non-unit elements. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}$ we have $2 = -1 \times -2$, but $-1$ is a unit so that doesn't count and so $2$ is **irreducible**. Compare $-10 = -2 \times 5$, in which neither $-2$ nor $5$ is a unit.

If you're only concerned with UFD's, then you don't have to worry about the difference between irreducibles and primes, they're the same. In non-UFD's, that's not always the case.

Comment: So 0 is reducible?

Comment: Maybe Bill meant "product of two or more non-zero non-unit elements" (per his previous paragraph). Though of course nothing prevents us from dividing 0 by other numbers.

Comment: @Robert Yeah, let's go with that. Seriously, though, if you accept the definition I gave as valid for nonzero elements, you should also accept it as valid for $0$. e.g., in $0 \times 3 = 0$, neither $0$ nor $3$ is a unit, which means that $0$ is indeed reducible. Whether this is of any practical value is debatable.